# How to make makefile find target in subdirectory makefile

Tags: makefile

How to make top level Makefile to call all targets in subdirectory Makefile ?

My folder structure is like this

```
/Makefile
/src/Makefile
```

I code all targets in `/src/Makefile`, but now I want to write another `/Makefile` to ease my work. How to write this top level Makefile ?

Comment: do you want the TOP `makefile` call sub `makefile`?

Comment: Do you mean all targets, or the `all` target?

Answer (score 8):

You could write in your TOP makefile use

```
all:
    @$(MAKE) -C src
```

and if you do NOT use makefile in sub dir, for example, you use somename.mk, you could use

```
all:
    @$(MAKE) -C src -f somename.mk
```

I show you my example, my DIR looks like:

```
TOPDIR-- Makefile
|
|-- debug
|   |-- debug.c
|   |-- debug.h
|   |-- debug.mk
|   |-- instrument.c
|   `-- uart_print.c
|-- driver
|   |-- driver.c
|   |-- driver_ddi.c
|   |-- driver_ddi.h
|   |-- driver.h
|   `-- driver.mk
|-- include
|   `-- common.h
|-- Makefile
|-- mw
|   |-- manager.c
|   `-- mw.mk
|-- root
|   |-- main.c
|   `-- root.mk
```

and my TOP makefile looks like:

```
MAKE_DIR = $(PWD)

ROOT_DIR    := $(MAKE_DIR)/root 
DRV_DIR     := $(MAKE_DIR)/driver
INCLUDE_DIR := $(MAKE_DIR)/include
DEBUG_DIR   := $(MAKE_DIR)/debug

INC_SRCH_PATH := 
INC_SRCH_PATH += -I$(ROOT_DIR)
INC_SRCH_PATH += -I$(DRV_DIR) 
INC_SRCH_PATH += -I$(INCLUDE_DIR)
INC_SRCH_PATH += -I$(DEBUG_DIR)

LIB_SRCH_PATH :=
LIB_SRCH_PATH += -L$(MAKE_DIR)/libs


COLOR_ON = color
COLOR_OFF = 
CC = $(COLOR_ON)gcc
#CC = $(COLOR_OFF)gcc
LD = ld

LINT = splint

LIBS := -ldriver -ldebug -lmw -lm -lpthread

CFLAGS :=
CFLAGS += $(INC_SRCH_PATH) $(LIB_SRCH_PATH) 
CFLAGS += -Wall -O -ggdb -Wstrict-prototypes -Wno-pointer-sign -finstrument-functions -fdump-rtl-expand
CFLAGS += -DDEBUG -D_REENTRANT

LDFLAGS :=

export MAKE_DIR CC LD CFLAGS LDFLAGS LIBS LINT INC_SRCH_PATH

all:
    @$(MAKE) -C debug -f debug.mk
    @$(MAKE) -C driver -f driver.mk
    @$(MAKE) -C mw -f mw.mk
    @$(MAKE) -C root -f root.mk

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(MAKE) -C debug -f debug.mk clean
    @$(MAKE) -C driver -f driver.mk clean
    @$(MAKE) -C mw -f mw.mk clean
    @$(MAKE) -C root -f root.mk clean

.PHONY: lint
lint:
    $(MAKE) -C debug -f debug.mk lint
```

it will call sub DIR *.mk during the compile. The sub DIR makefile, I just write a simple example for you reference:

```
LIB = $(MAKE_DIR)/libs/yourmodulename.a
SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRCS))

$(LIB): $(OBJS)
    @mkdir -p ../libs
    @$(AR) cr $@ $^
    @echo "    Archive    $(notdir $@)"

$(OBJS): $(SRCS)
    @$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c $^
    @echo "    CC        $(OBJS)"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(RM) -f $(LIB) $(OBJS)
    @$(RM) -f *.expand
    @echo "    Remove Objects:   $(OBJS)"
    @echo "    Remove Libraries:  $(notdir $(LIB))"

.PHONY: lint 
lint:
    $(LINT) $(INC_SRCH_PATH) $(SRCS)
```

for the makefile, which generate the target file is little bit different, because I use the sub makefile to generate LIB file, and I use a `root.mk` to generate target:

```
PROG = ../prog/DEMO

SRCS = $(wildcard *.c)
OBJS = $(patsubst %.c, %.o, $(SRCS))

$(PROG): $(SRCS)
    @mkdir -p ../prog
    @$(CC) $^ $(CFLAGS) -Wl,-Map=$(PROG).map $(LIBS) -o $@
    @echo "    Generate Program $(notdir $(PROG)) from $^"

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    @$(RM) -f $(OBJS) $(PROG)
    @$(RM) -f *.expand
    @$(RM) -rf ../prog ../libs
    @echo "    Remove Objects:   $(OBJS)"
    @echo "    Remove Libraries:  $(notdir $(PROG))"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but does `all` match any targets? Or the `all` is just an example of one of targets?

Comment: @guilin 桂林, in my `makefile`, I think `all` match any targets of my project

Answer (score 5):

Beware, note there are, at least, two ways of doing this.

**GNU Changedir Option**

One way is using a specific feature of GNU Make, the `-C` option allow to change your compile directory and reach another one:

```
all:
    make -C dir
```

The `make` manual says:

> ```
> -C dir, --directory=dir
>     Change to directory dir before reading the makefiles or doing anything
>     else. If multiple -C options are specified, each is interpreted relative
>     to the previous one: -C / -C etc is equivalent to -C  /etc. This is
>     typically used with recursive invocations of make.
> ```

You can also combine this option by calling a specific target inside the targeted directory. For example, the following target will get into the `src/` directory and call `make` with the `clean` target:

```
clean:
        @rm -f *.o
        make -C src/ clean
```

**POSIX Way**

The problem with the GNU way of doing is that it only works with GNU Make, and not the standard Make. If you may use another Make (for whatever reason), you better consider doing it in a more POSIX way.

In POSIX Make, you have to rely more on the `cd` command, like this:

```
all:
        cd src/ && make
```

Note that, I used `&&` and not `;`. It is quite important to avoid infinite recursive calls to `make`. Indeed, `cmd1 ; cmd2` will execute sequentially `cmd1` and `cmd2` whatever is the result of each command, where `cmd1 && cmd2` will execute sequentially `cmd1`, and `cmd2` will be executed only if `cmd1` returned an `EXIT_SUCCESS`. In our case, imagine that the first `cd` failed because the directory has been removed. Then, the initial makefile will be executed again and again in an infinite recursive loop.

Anyway, this POSIX manner, is the more robust way of descending in subdirectories and execute other Makefile. I would recommend you to use it better than relying on an option linked to GNU Make.

Comment: thanks! I added an extension to this below to show how to extend this to multiple dirs.

Answer (score 1):

And if you want to do multiple dirs easily:

```
SUBDIRS=dir1 dir2

all::
        @echo make all
        $(foreach var,$(SUBDIRS),echo $(var): ; cd $(var)/ && make $@ && cd ..;)
clean:
        @echo make clean
        $(foreach var,$(SUBDIRS),echo $(var): ; cd $(var)/ && make $@ && cd ..;)
```